# Flutter webview_flutter package handshake failed

Tags: flutter, ssl, webview, chromium

When trying to load html file using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package it takes time until loading while printing this error then it loads the webview

```
E/chromium(27944): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

What could trigger such an error?

Flutter and Webview versions:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11)

webview_flutter: ^4.0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By debugging the webview errors like this: (Only works on Android)

```
onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            log("RESOURCE ERROR DESCRIPTION ${error.description}");
            log("RESOURCE ERROR CODE ${error.errorCode}");
            log("RESOURCE ERROR Error Type ${error.errorType}");
            log("RESOURCE ERROR Failing URL ${error.url}");
          },
```

I could find that the source of the errors is some UI resources in the website itself like `Popper` causes this error